# create new user in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, postman

I am trying to write a function that creates a user in mongoose. when I try to test it in postman, it shows that the user could not be created.

```
export function create(req, res) {

    User.create(req.body, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(400).send('Couldn\'t create new user');
        }

        return res.status(201).send('new user created.');
    });
}
```

here is the model.js:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;


let nameSchema = Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true}
});

let userSchema = Schema({
    name: nameSchema,
    username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true}
});
let User = mongoose.model('OtherUser', userSchema);
export {User};
```

and here is the postman request:

```json
{
    "name": {
        "firstName": "mike",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    "username": "mike",
    "email": "mike@mike.com"
}
```

any ideas, thanks
(note: I use the exact format and does not create a new user. I am also sure that username and email is unique)

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide the validation schema for `User` and the content of your request in Postman. I believe there's an option on Postman to copy your request as cURL or fetch

Comment: @hugh I did update my question

Comment: Can you use save instead of create?

Comment: @RifatBinReza I did it but it shows an error that save is not a function

Comment: @Meem Can you show me how you're importing the `User` model in your controller? I think there's a problem with your import

Comment: @RifatBinReza import {User} from './users.model';

Comment: from your code, I cannot identify any problems then. Can you provide the err log?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229188/discussion-between-rifat-bin-reza-and-meem).